# Don't understand why does this code raises an EOF error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Python 3 program on Windows 10 that loops through Unicode characters, but on the last empty line, it has the error of

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I tried putting a `print("Done!")` at the end but that said 
`IndentationError: unexpected unindent`.

```
max = int("FFFC",16)
min = 0
for x in range(max + 1):
    try:
        hex_value = hex(x)
        proper = str(hex_value)[2:].upper()
        while len(proper) != 4:
            proper = "0" + proper
        proper = "U+" + str(proper)
        print(f"{proper} : {chr(x)}")
```

Error:

```
    File "unicode.py", line 11
                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This is in the last line of code (where it is blank).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include an `except` statement for every `try`.